# Designing a Database connection pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling

How to go about this question, if it's asked in an interview setting.

> **How would you design a database connection pool. Give a high level overview of classes and interfaces that will be involved and how they interact**

Comment: more to the point, how would YOU about answering this question??

Comment: You can learn it yourself!! :) Try looking at the source code of the apache project DBCP. [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)

Comment: What is the point of you asking this question here?  The interviewers don't want a rehearsed answer.  They want to see how good YOU are at solving "big picture" problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take a look at the [Object Pool](http://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern.html) design pattern